How to transform the volume integral of a curl of the product of a potential with a magnetic field into a surface integral?
Problem 6.5 of Jackson electrodynamics says:

A localized electric charge distribution produces an electrostatic field, $\vec{E} = - \vec{\nabla}\Phi$. Into this field is placed a small localized time-dependent current density $\vec{J} (\vec{X})$, which generates a magnetic field $\vec{H}$. (a) Show that the momentum of these electromagnetic fields, [given by equation] (6.117), can be transformed to $$ \vec{P}_{field} = \frac{1}{c^2} \int \Phi \vec{J} d^3x, $$ provided the product $\Phi \vec{H}$ falls off rapidly enough at large distances. How rapidly is "rapidly enough"?

For reference, equation (6.117) of Jackson reads:
$$
\vec{P}_{field} = \varepsilon_0 \int_v \vec{E} \times \vec{B}\ d^3x = \mu_0 \varepsilon_0 \int_V \vec{E} \times \vec{H}\ d^3x.
$$
We can use the identity $\vec{\nabla} \times (\psi \vec{a}) = \vec{\nabla} \psi \times \vec{a} + \psi \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{a}$, so that
$$
c^2 \vec{P}_{field} = \int_V \Phi \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{H}\ d^3x - \int_V \vec{\nabla} \times (\Phi \vec{H})\ d^3x
$$
By the Maxwell equations, $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{H} = \vec{J} + \frac{\partial \vec{D}}{\partial t}$, and the first integral becomes the one in the problem's statement, given that the current density is time-independent.
The problem I'm having is what to do with the second integral. I saw somewhere that we could transform it into a surface integral such like
$$
\int_V \vec{\nabla} \times (\Phi \vec{H})\ d^3x = \int_S \Phi\vec{H}\ d\vec{a}.
$$
This brings into the discussion the product $\Phi\vec{H}$, specially if it falls off rapidly. I cannot see this transformation straight away and I don't really know if that is true. Can someone help?

(1) You need a $\times $ sign between $\vec H$ and $d\vec a$ in the last integral formula. The integral identity is also listed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities under "Surface–volume integrals" and can be proved by applying the divergence theorem to $\vec e \times \vec A$ for $\vec e$ a constant vector field.  (2) If  the charges and currents are of finite extent then $\Phi  \sim \tfrac{1}{r}$ and $H  \sim \tfrac{1}{r^2}$ so the surface integral does go to zero for $r \to \infty$.
